# show RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR when the value i insert did not meet the previous value

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

i trying to use trigger to show RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR when the new value i insert did not follow the previous value. for example my latest position are on second position and when i want to insert new position which is 10 , it should show the ORA-… "the error message i type " ?? anyone can help me edit my code ?? do i need a select statement for this one ??

```
SET ECHO ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET serveroutput on size 2000 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RowTrigger
Before 
 INSERT OR UPDATE on POSITION
 FOR EACH ROW
 declare
 u number(2);

begin
 select count(P#) into u from POSITION ;

  if :new.P# < u
  then
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011,'dddd');
 end if;

 end;
```

Comment: It can work, you question isn't clear, how do you execute and what is the error exactly

Comment: @user7294900 for example in my database my latest p# is 2 , i want when the user input new p# , it should be 3 , if it is not 3 then the error message i type must come out

Comment: @diu1997 are executing the procedure in command line ? maybe you need to add `set serveroutput on size 2000`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It took me sometimes to write it, the below working taking on consideration:

```
-The P# is unique, or youll get error in the select.
-I am not taking on consideration the previous data , for example  if your P# is 5 and ur inserting 3, then youll not have error.
   if you need such thing you can continue developing it because there are some conditions to be met.
-The table already contains data , all you can add a exception NO_data_found and do whatever you want in that case.
```

this is the code:

```
drop table ex_employee
/
create table ex_employee (id number(2) null,id1 number(2) NULL,name varchar2(1000) null)

/
drop table POSITION
/
create table POSITION(p# number(2) null)
/
insert into POSITION(p#) values (4)
/
insert into POSITION(p#) values (5)
/
commit
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RowTrigger
  FOR INSERT on POSITION compound trigger
     prevID number(4);
     new_p number(4);
  after each row is
begin

  new_p := :new.p#;
end after each row;

  after statement is
     begin 
     --it gives the previous record;
        select PREV_ID into prevID from(SELECt p#, LAG(p#, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY p#) as PREV_ID FROM position) where p# = new_p;
      -- check if the old data is smaller then the new, you can add more conditions.
            if (previd < new_p) then
      previd:=previd+1;
      end if;

     IF (prevID != new_p) THEN 
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011, 'ERROR , data not in order or whatever.');
     END IF; 


   end  after statement;

end;
/
```

Comment: i have edit my code , but now what i want is , as you can see my latest db the p# is at 2 , i want when the user input new p# , it should be 3 , if it is not 3 then the error message i type must come out